# Insert into table where something in another table is true

Tags: mysql

I'm running a MySQL event every second, and in this event, I want to check if any users have been registered for a certain amount of time. If they have, I want to insert a row into another table called "achievements".

I store the user's registration date as a timestamp (integer) in a field called called "regtime" in a table called "users", and I'd like to keep the checking to seconds, so I can do something like:

```
if time now - regtime (total time registered) = certain amount of seconds, insert row into achievements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `achievements`
    (`user_id`, `field1`, `field2`, `fieldX`)
SELECT `id`, 'field1Value', 'field2Value', 'fieldXValue'
FROM `users`
WHERE (NOW() - `regtime`) > @certain_amount_of_seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:

```
INSERT INTO achievements (message, logtime, category)
SELECT msg, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'info'
FROM user
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(join_date)) > 360000
```

In the above query we have following key things:

**msg --** This field is from user table. We could say user.msg
**UNIX_TIMESTAMP()** -- Current unix timestamp
**'info'** -- This is a constant that will be inserted with every entry